# Can or should UDP be routed through a proxy?

Tags: c#

I have a TCP/IP proxy socket implementation that works well for Socks 4, Socks 5, and HTTP.  I have a need to get MX Records through UDP.  When there is a proxy, is UDP traffic routed through a proxy or not?  Is it even possible to do that?  If so, where could I find an example of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routing in general is IP-based. So sending a UDP packet through a proxy is of course possible. There are even some simple scripts that do it here: [simple udp proxy solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803329/simple-udp-proxy-solution)

If it is possible in your case - it depends on the proxy you are using.