# How can I count each UDP packet sent out by subprocesses?

Tags: python, linux, sockets, networking

I have a Python application which orchestrates calls to an underlying process. The processes are called using `subprocess.check_output` and they make SNMP calls to remote network devices.

For performance monitoring, I would like to count the number of sent SNMP packets which are transmitted. I am primarily interested in the *count* of the packets. Packet size of request/response would be interesting too, but less important. The aim is to have an idea on the firewall stress this application causes.

So, for the sake of argument, let's assume the following silly application:

```
from subprocess import check_output
output = check_output(['snmpget', '-v2c', '-c', 'private', '192.168.1.1', '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0'])
print(output)
```

This would cause a new UDP packet to be sent out on port 161.

How can I count them in such a case?

Here's another version with stubbed functions (could also be a context manager):

```
from subprocess import check_call


def start_monitoring():
    pass


def stop_monitoring():
    return 0


start_monitoring()
check_call(['snmpget', '-v2c', '-c', 'private', '192.168.1.1', '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0'])
check_call(['snmpget', '-v2c', '-c', 'private', '192.168.1.1', '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0'])
check_call(['snmpget', '-v2c', '-c', 'private', '192.168.1.1', '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0'])
num_connections = stop_monitoring()
assert num_connections == 3
```

In this contrived example, it will obviously be 3 calls, as I manually execute the SNMP calls. But in the practical example, the number of SNMP calls is not equal to calls to the subprocess. Sometimes one or more GETs are executed, sometimes it's simple walks (that is, a *lot* of sequential UDP requests) sometimes it's bulk walks (an unknown amount of requests).

So I can't simply monitor the amount of times the application is called. I really have to monitor the UDP requests.

Is something like that even possible? If yes, how?

It's likely important to know that this runs on Linux as non-root user. But all subprocesses run as the same user.

Comment: UDP is a connectionless protocol, so there is no such thing as a UDP connection. If you need connections, you can use TCP, a connection-oriented protocol.

Comment: My wording was badly chosen indeed. What I meant was: "count the number of packets that are sent out on UDP port 161". I'll reword the question in a minute.

Comment: Shouldn't the load on the firewall (dropped packets, CPU load, etc) be measured _at the firewall_? In other words, is this an XY problem?

Comment: The firewall is managed by a different team, and I don't have access to it. What's more, the same machine runs several applications using SNMP. So this solution would also count the packets of other applications.

Comment: You should try with this https://github.com/raboof/nethogs Its good utility to monitor network traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40557980/160665), [this github repo](https://github.com/EtiennePerot/misc-scripts/blob/0ec3dfe/udp-relay.py) via [yet another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9736646/160665), I came up with the following implementation of a UDP Proxy/Relay:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from collections import namedtuple
from contextlib import contextmanager
from random import randint
from time import sleep
import logging
import socket
import threading

import snmp


MSG_DONTWAIT = 0x40  # from socket.h
LOCK = threading.Lock()

MSG_TYPE_REQUEST = 1
MSG_TYPE_RESPONSE = 2
Statistics = namedtuple('Statistics', 'msgtype packet_size')


def visible_octets(data: bytes) -> str:
    """
    Returns a geek-friendly (hexdump)  output of a bytes object.

    Developer note:
        This is not super performant. But it's not something that's supposed to
        be run during normal operations (mostly for testing and debugging).  So
        performance should not be an issue, and this is less obfuscated than
        existing solutions.

    Example::

        >>> from os import urandom
        >>> print(visible_octets(urandom(40)))
        99 1f 56 a9 25 50 f7 9b  95 7e ff 80 16 14 88 c5   ..V.%P...~......
        f3 b4 83 d4 89 b2 34 b4  71 4e 5a 69 aa 9f 1d f8   ......4.qNZi....
        1d 33 f9 8e f1 b9 12 e9                            .3......

    """
    from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify

    hexed = hexlify(data).decode('ascii')
    tuples = [''.join((a, b)) for a, b in zip(hexed[::2], hexed[1::2])]
    line = []
    output = []
    ascii_column = []
    for idx, octet in enumerate(tuples):
        line.append(octet)
        # only use printable characters in ascii output
        ascii_column.append(octet if 32 <= int(octet, 16) < 127 else '2e')
        if (idx+1) % 8 == 0:
            line.append('')
        if (idx+1) % 8 == 0 and (idx+1) % 16 == 0:
            raw_ascii = unhexlify(''.join(ascii_column))
            raw_ascii = raw_ascii.replace(b'\\n z', b'.')
            ascii_column = []
            output.append('%-50s %s' % (' '.join(line),
                                        raw_ascii.decode('ascii')))
            line = []
    raw_ascii = unhexlify(''.join(ascii_column))
    raw_ascii = raw_ascii.replace(b'\\n z', b'.')
    output.append('%-50s %s' % (' '.join(line), raw_ascii.decode('ascii')))
    line = []
    return '\n'.join(output)


@contextmanager
def UdpProxy(remote_host, remote_port, queue=None):
    thread = UdpProxyThread(remote_host, remote_port, stats_queue=queue)
    thread.prime()
    thread.start()
    yield thread.local_port
    thread.stop()
    thread.join()


class UdpProxyThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, remote_host, remote_port, stats_queue=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.local_port = randint(60000, 65535)
        self.remote_host = remote_host
        self.remote_port = remote_port
        self.daemon = True
        self.log = logging.getLogger('%s.%s' % (
            __name__, self.__class__.__name__))
        self.running = True
        self._socket = None
        self.stats_queue = stats_queue

    def fail(self, reason):
        self.log.debug('UDP Proxy Failure: %s', reason)
        self.running = False

    def prime(self):
        """
        We need to set up a socket on a FREE port for this thread. Retry until
        we find a free port.

        This is used as a separate method to ensure proper locking and to ensure
        that each thread has it's own port

        The port can be retrieved by accessing the *local_port* member of the
        thread.
        """
        with LOCK:
            while True:
                try:
                    self._socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
                                                 socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
                    self._socket.bind(('', self.local_port))
                    break
                except OSError as exc:
                    self.log.warning('Port %d already in use. Shuffling...',
                                     self.local_port)
                    if exc.errno == 98:  # Address already in use
                        self.local_port = randint(60000, 65535)
                        self._socket.close()
                    else:
                        raise

    @property
    def name(self):
        return 'UDP Proxy Thread {} -> {}:{}'.format(self.local_port,
                                                     self.remote_host,
                                                     self.remote_port)

    def start(self):
        if not self._socket:
            raise ValueError('Socket was not set. Call prime() first!')
        super().start()

    def run(self):
        try:
            known_client = None
            known_server = (self.remote_host, self.remote_port)
            self.log.info('UDP Proxy set up: %s -> %s:%s',
                          self.local_port, self.remote_host, self.remote_port)
            while self.running:
                try:
                    data, addr = self._socket.recvfrom(32768, MSG_DONTWAIT)
                    self.log.debug('Packet received via %s\n%s', addr,
                                   visible_octets(data))
                except BlockingIOError:
                    sleep(0.1)  # Give self.stop() a chance to trigger
                else:
                    if known_client is None:
                        known_client = addr
                    if addr == known_client:
                        self.log.debug('Proxying request packet to %s\n%s',
                                       known_server, visible_octets(data))
                        self._socket.sendto(data, known_server)
                        if self.stats_queue:
                            self.stats_queue.put(Statistics(
                                MSG_TYPE_REQUEST, len(data)))
                    else:
                        self.log.debug('Proxying response packet to %s\n%s',
                                       known_client, visible_octets(data))
                        self._socket.sendto(data, known_client)
                        if self.stats_queue:
                            self.stats_queue.put(Statistics(
                                MSG_TYPE_RESPONSE, len(data)))
            self.log.info('%s stopped!', self.name)
        finally:
            self._socket.close()

    def stop(self):
        self.log.debug('Stopping %s...', self.name)
        self.running = False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=0)
    from queue import Queue
    stat_queue = Queue()

    with UdpProxy('192.168.1.1', 161, stat_queue) as proxied_port:
        print(snmp.get('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0', '127.0.0.1:%s' % proxied_port,
                       'testing'))
    with UdpProxy('192.168.1.1', 161, stat_queue) as proxied_port:
        print(snmp.get('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0', '127.0.0.1:%s' % proxied_port,
                       'testing'))

    while not stat_queue.empty():
        stat_item = stat_queue.get()
        print(stat_item)
        stat_queue.task_done()
```

As seen in the `__main__` section, it can simply be used as follows:

```
    from queue import Queue
    stat_queue = Queue()

    with UdpProxy('192.168.1.1', 161, stat_queue) as proxied_port:
        print(snmp.get('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0', '127.0.0.1:%s' % proxied_port,
                       'testing'))

    while not stat_queue.empty():
        stat_item = stat_queue.get()
        print(stat_item)
        stat_queue.task_done()
```

One thing to note: the `snmp` module in this case simply executes a `subprocess.check_output()` to spawn a `snmpget` subprocess.

Answer (score 2):

This might help you:

https://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/

> The tcpdumplike.stp prints out a line for each TCP & UDP packet received. Each line includes the source and destination IP addresses, the source and destination ports, and flags.

The code is not written in python but converting it is no big deal.

Answer (score 1):

You can write another python application which connects to the local network adapter in promiscuous mode. In this mode you will see all the traffic going through your network adapter. And then you can filter the `UDP` traffic from them and finally filtering the packets which has a source port 161. But this needs to run as root or priviledged user.

```
import socket

# the public network interface
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

# create a raw socket and bind it to the public interface
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
s.bind((HOST, 0))

# Include IP headers
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)

# receive all packages
s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)

# receive a package
print s.recvfrom(65565)

# disabled promiscuous mode
s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_OFF)
```

[Source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html)

Comment: I wonder: why a separate process? Would this not be possible to add to the existing application as well? Granted, you'd need SU privileges, and will also capture any packages from other applications made during that time, but this would already be a very good start...

Comment: You can if you can run your application as a root or privileged user.

Comment: Do you think that this is the only way to solve this? Given that the application will only capture packets which its own children send, I wonder if there is no other trickery possible to run this even as a restricted user. Alternatively, what do you think about setting kernel capabilities to avoid running the whole app as privileged user?

Comment: There may be other ways but I doubt the accuracy. Since you mentioned there may be multiple UDP packets being sent as well. This is quite reliable approach.

Comment: I'm keeping this open for a while. As there's a bounty attached to it, I want to give people a chance to chime in. While not 100% solving the problem at hand your answer is a very good approximation. And I don't know if it's even possible to do what I'm asking for. So an approximation is acceptable. Might be good to add arguments *why* this is the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, but you could use a UDP proxy and simply count the messages sent/received by the proxy.  A simple proxy is already available on SO: [simple udp proxy solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803329/simple-udp-proxy-solution).  It would be trivial to add counters to the solutions presented here.

If you need to run them in parallel, simply use different ports for each process.  Otherwise, you could just reuse the same proxy port for each new process.

Comment: Thanks. This got me going. I'll add an answer with the final code for posterity. I ended up having a solution which behaves just like I wanted: a context manager! That ended up being really convenient.

Comment: @exhuma Nice job!  That's exactly the sort of solution I was thinking of...

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, since you report that you don't have access to the firewall configuration (I assume you also mean the *local* firewall--netfilter exists whether or not it's being used for anything) there are really precious few options available to you.

There's a few command-line options you might look into on the snmpcmd man page.  Notably, the -d option will dump the contents of each packet sent and will be somewhat unpleasant to parse, but at least it's there (even if the address output is wrong on some platforms).  Frankly, this is probably your best bet taking your requirements into consideration.

There is also (and this will be *extremely* unpleasant) the option of scribbling up a UDP proxy of your own to simply act as a go-between for the various SNMP utilities, relaying (after counting) each packet yourself.  No elevated privileges will be necessary for this because SNMP **does not** require a *source* port of 161--it's completely satisfied to answer queries from any high port you send them.  So, you can bind to whatever port on the localhost interface you wish, and point your SNMP tool at that port with the proxy simply repeating everything it sees back and forth to the "real" destination.

Honestly tho', unless the remote firewall is running on a stale potato, firewalling duties will never pose a significant CPU load unless you have literally *many thousands* of rules.

Answer (score 0):

`snmpget` in particular allows you to pass `-d` flag, logging the packets sent to stdout (can be redirected).

```
$ snmpget -d -v2c -c private 192.168.1.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0
No log handling enabled - using stderr logging

Sending 44 bytes to UDP: [192.168.1.1]:161->[0.0.0.0]:0
. . .

Timeout: No Response from 192.168.1.1.
```

If your tested processes are not under your control, I'd prefer using something requiring no coding: `tcpdump` or `strace`. From my experience it is possible to request limited sudoers entry from your sysops/devops people when arguments of the call / the purpose is very confined.

If sudoers modifications is absolute no-no, you can direct your tested application to a hand crafted proxy app configured to send the packets further and which will be doing the counting.